# Access session object retrieves a string afer migrating Django 1.8

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

I migrated my ecommerce project to django 1.8 and I am not being able to access the shopcart session. I store users shopcart as an object in the session and then request.session to access. 
This object now is considered a String so I am not being able to add/remove/etc items or modify it.

```
cart = get_shopping_cart(request)  #if I print(cart) I get <obj>
cart.add_item(prod, prod.img, prod.UMP, int(quan), prod.price) #error


def get_shopping_cart(request, cart_class=Cart):
    return request.session.get('cart', None) or cart_class()
```

I have tried adding session_serialize in settings.py but it doesnt work. I think it has to do with this newer django version, but which would be the correct way to solve it ?  Should I change all session to store only the Id (the object should be stored in DB ?) ? or write my own serializer ?

Thanks.

My Cart:

```
class Cart(object):
    class Item(object):
        def __init__(self, itemid, product, image, quantity=1, price=0):
            self.image = image
            self.itemid = itemid
            self.product = product
            self.quantity = quantity
            self.price = price


        def __init__(self):
            self.items = list()
            self.unique_item_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing a `cart_id` in the session is one possibility. Another possibility is to modify you `get_shopping_cart` class so that it deserialises the string stored in the session.

```
def get_shopping_cart(request, cart_class=Cart):
    if 'cart' in request.session:
        session = string_to_cart(request.session['cart'])
    else:
        session = cart_class()
    return session
```

Comment: thank for your answer. 'string_to_cart' would be a custom deserialiser ?

Comment: Yes, `string_to_cart` would be a custom deserializer. You didn't include any information about your `Cart` class or the string stored in the session, so that bit of the code is up to you!